# jQuery: use of wrap() on <img> element IE error

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

This works perfectly fine in all browsers but the Internet Explorer:

```
$newContent.wrap("<img src='" + $altContent + "' />");
```

The `wrap` seems to fail on the  element. How do I resolve this?

Comment: In `IE6` perhaps? ;)  But seriously.. what version?  That's kind of an  important detail :)

Answer (score 3):

The `img` tag is a self-closing tag, as you can even see in the code you posted (it ends with `/>`). So the idea of wrapping an element in an image tag doesn't make any sense. For example:

```
<img src="">
    <div></div>
</img>
```

That is invalid markup, and its essentially what you're telling jQuery to try doing. If it works in other browsers, that's only because they are guessing correctly at what you really want to do. For once Internet Explorer isn't actually making any mistake at all -- you are :)